# How to automatically close reward ad after rewarded [Android-Studio]

Tags: java, android-studio

So i'm trying to have it automatically close the ad after it rewards the user here is what I got so far.

Keep in mind i'm new to android studio and java as a whole. If they are spaced they are in different methods.

```
private RewardedVideoAd mAd;

AdView adView;
void init_admob(){
    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}


public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, reward.getAmount()+ " " +getString(R.string.points_received), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    award(reward.getAmount(),getString(R.string.admob_credit));
    exitAd();
}


public void exitAd() {
    //dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)); Tried But didn't work (No Errors Just didn't work)
    //dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)); Tried but didn't work (No Errors Just didn't work)
    try {
        LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        linLay.removeView(adView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error For linLay

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

So I don't really know what else to try or how to close the AdView after the ad has rewarded any help is apperciated!

Comment: Both your `adView` and `linLay` refer to `findViewById(R.id.adView)`. So `linLay.removeView(adView);` means remove itself from itself, which is not possible. You have to find the parent view containing `adView` and call `removeView(adView)` on the parent view.

Comment: @RickyMo Where can I find this parent view?

Comment: That's the view enclosing the `adView` in the layout file. Or you can simply do this : `((ViewGroup)adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);`

Comment: So it would be `ViewGroup linLay = (ViewGroup)adView.getParent();
            linLay.removeView(adView);` essentially

Comment: Yes, you can try that out.

Comment: @RickyMo Didn't work for me, no error it just didn't close the ad. Is there a way to just got back to the previous screen?

Comment: How do you open this screen?

Comment: @RickyMo    `private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        if (!mAd.isLoaded()) {
            mAd.loadAd(getResources().getString(R.string.ad), new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }`  than just use .show

Comment: try `mAd.destroy(this)`;

Comment: @RickyMo doesn't seem like that worked either.

Comment: @RickyMo You think it'd be easier to just handle it in another activity and just use finish?

Comment: its seems that you have two ads, an `AdView` and a `RewardedVideoAd`. Which one is not closing? I guess `RewardedVideoAd` will close automatically after finish playback?

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that is possible. It would also be not right legally. When you show an ad, you should wait for the user to either click or cancel the ad. If you close programmatically, it would mean you have effectively forced the user to cancel the ad. (It may be good for the user, but think from the advertiser's perspective)

Answer (score 0):

You cant close the ad in-app but here is what I have done.

```
private fun showRewardedVideo() {
    if (mRewardedAd.isLoaded) {
      mRewardedAd.show(
              this,
              object : RewardedAdCallback() {
                  override fun onUserEarnedReward(
                          rewardItem: RewardItem
                  ) {
                      Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "onUserEarnedReward", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                      addCoins(rewardItem.amount)
                     // come back to ad activity
                      startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity2::class.java))
                  }
```